# I want to get a file from windows machine to unix machine using sshapss command

Tags: unix

whn I try to connect windows  server  from my unix  manually I am able  to get the  file  .

```
sshpass -p "passwd" sftp username@hosname:path
get filnename unipath
```

I tired  above lines manually and I am able to pull file to my unix path .When tried executing  same  commands  via shell script  its throwing  below  error. Can some one help me .

```
SSHPASS: Failed to run command: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Can some one help me  to resolve the issue .

Comment: have you try with `ssh-agent`?

Comment: I am not  aware  of  SSH-agent  ..Can you elaborate ??

Comment: https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/agent